# Home files and folders permissions could not be determined

Tags: bash, permissions, ownership

I  was trying to create a default configuration file for activemq with the command

```
sudo ./activemq setup [ /etc/default/activemq | /home/leo/.activemqrc ]`
```

Then  recieved this message:

```
INFO: It's recommend to limit access to '/etc/default/activemq' to the priviledged user
INFO: (recommended: chown 'root':nogroup '/etc/default/activemq'; chmod 600 '/etc/default/activemq')
```

Then I changed the owner and permissions of both `/etc/default/activemq` and `/home/leo/.activemqrc` with

```
chown root:nogroup ~/activemqrc; chmod 600 ~/.activemqrc
```

Changing the permissions of ~/.activemqrc was undoubtedly a big mistake. I took a look at the permissions on each file and folder on my Home and it says:

```
The permissions of "Everything" could not be determined
```

I no longer can access the directories and files in home.

---

Following the answer from [Permission denied on ~ even though owner listed as me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94321/permission-denied-on-even-though-owner-listed-as-me) I ran the following command:

```
find ~ -type d -exec chmod 750 \;
```

and got this output:

```
find: pred.c:1932: launch: Assertion `starting_desc >= 0' failed.
```

---

Is there any way to get back my default configurations?

**EDIT**

I then tried this:

```
sudo chown root:root ~/
```

got no output
and then

```
sudo chmod -R  777 ~/
```

That pretty much solved my problem but for two files which returned

```
chmod: cannot access `/home/leo/.gvfs': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `/home/leo/.config/google-chrome/.com.google.Chrome.Z07tM9': No    such file or directory.
```

**THAT WAS JUST A BAD IDEA.**

Comment: @Alex, no, do not use RT*M, we don't accept bad language in any way, disguised or not. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23628/how-should-we-deal-with-rtfm-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first attempt to fix it was just missing `'{}'` but then you made things a lot worse...

There is hardly ever a reason for any file to have `777` permissions, and there is hardly even a good use case for the `-R` flag when using `chmod`, because we need directories to be executable in order to enter or stat them, but we rarely want all files to be executable.

First, `chown` your home directory. Logged in as yourself, run

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~
```

If you have simply run something like

```
chmod 600 ~
```

Then revert it:

```
chmod 755 ~
```

However, if you have run something really ill-advised like (**do not execute**) `chmod -R 777 ~`, then fixing the permissions will be more tricky.

`find` is very helpful for this. Directory permissions in your home will vary, and could be `700`, `775`, `755` or `750`. To err on the side of caution, I would do this:

```
find ~ -type d -exec chmod 700 '{}' +
```

So only you can access the directories. You could instead use `755` and then correct these modes:

```
chmod 700 ~/.local ~/.cache ~/.dbus ~/.thumbnails ~/.gconf ~/.thunderbird
```

Then files. You might have had some executable scripts in your home but in general files should not be executable. Most files in your home would probably have had `664` or `644` permission, but again to be safe you might want to go with

```
find ~ -type f -exec chmod 600 '{}' +
```

This makes it so only you can access the files and directories in your home. If you prefer, Use `644` instead, and then correct the mode of the `Xauthority` file and a few others:

```
chmod 600 ~/.Xauthority ~/.ICEauthority ~/.bash_history ~/.local/share/keyrings/* ~/.xsession-errors ~/.lesshst
```

If you want to be really thorough, you can install a fresh Ubuntu VM or check the permissions of `~` on another machine... something like

```
find ~ -type d -not -perm 700 -exec stat -c "%n %a" {} \; | tee dirperms
```

and

```
find ~ -type f -not -perm 600 -exec stat -c "%n %a" {} \; | tee fileperms
```

Will generate lists you can use to make corrections.